# Add a .a library to cmake project

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries

I have a `libname.a` static library that works fine when I use gcc:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o ;
gcc main.o libname.a main
```

But now I would like to use CMake as the project is getting big, but I got this message and and I don't know how to include it in an appropriate way. (I tried `link_target_library` and/or `link_directories` and/or `set(CMAKE_CC_FLAGS "absolute_path/libname.a")`.

Note that I don't have any source code for `libname.a`.

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibname

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libname.a)` when the library is next to CMakeLists.txt works for me

Comment: regarding: `gcc main.o libname.a main`  this is not correct, perhaps your meant; `gcc -static main.o -o main -l name`

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libname.a)` works. I can't really tell what the reason for your problem is (maybe you used `target_link_library` instead of `target_link_libraries` ?).